# docker wsl 2 is not installed

Tags: docker, wsl-2

After installing docker desktop, I get an error

Error - WSL 2 is not installed.

[image: error 1]

[image: after click use Hyper-v]

Of course I tried to fix this. But all the solutions I found boil down to the fact that I have to enable Hyper-V. However, I cannot turn it on because it simply does not exist on my windows 10 computer, but I cannot download it either, because it should already be downloaded by default

Every time I try to enable hyper-v through the console or in other ways, I am told that it is not on my PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log in as Admin an go to Settings - > Apps and Features - > Programms and Features - > turn Windows Feature on or off - > activate HyperV and WSL

or the Windows Version does not provide Hyper V like Windows 10 Home

[https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/hyper-v-feature-did-not-available-in-window-10/de7b7a68-d060-4a44-ae4c-ed2119c834fa?auth=1][1]

Comment: Of course I tried it, but there is no hyper-v

Comment: Hi maybe you are using Windows 10 Home instead of Pro:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/hyper-v-feature-did-not-available-in-window-10/de7b7a68-d060-4a44-ae4c-ed2119c834fa?auth=1

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME:**

If Linux container is used, run the following in Command Prompt (Admin):

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart

dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

(if wsl 2 linux kernel is already installed, run the following as well)
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

If Windows container is used, run the following in Powershell (Admin):

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All
```

Comment: Powershell command worked for me , , I didn't try accepted answer , tried this one first and this worked,  so up voted

Answer (score 0):

If Windows use download this update

https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi